# how to get result with group by and count of fileds in MySql

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

my table

```
CNT_ID  REGION   GRADE  MAX-CAPACITY  TOTAL-CAPACITY LASTDATE

1001    TN       FOOD   97             100            2020-02-17
1001    BG       BEV    76              90            2020-02-17
1001    KA       IND    88              90            2020-02-17
1001    BG       FOOD   91             100            2020-02-17
1001    ER       IND    90             100            2020-02-15
1001    TN       FOOD   78              80            2020-02-17
1001    TN       BEV    95             100            2020-02-17
1001    TN       FOOD   92             100            2020-02-16
```

I want to get result based on... list by REGIONS -> AND COUNT OF MaxCapacity of(FOOD, BEV, IND) AND ORDERED BY LASTDATE desc

result expected:

```
REGION  FOODGRADE   BEVGRADE    INDGRADE    TOTALCAPACITY   LEFT    LASTDATE
TN      267             95          0       380             18      2020-02-17
BG      91              76          0       190             23      2020-02-17
KA      0               0           88      90              2       2020-02-17
ER      0               0           90      100             10      2020-02-17
```

I TRIED THE FOLLOWING... but no luck:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(GRADE='FOOD',1,NULL)) 'Food', COUNT(IF(GRADE='BEV',1,NULL)) 'Beve', * 
FROM txn_viewinfo  
WHERE LASTDATE = (SELECT MAX(LASTDATE) 
                  FROM txn_viewinfo ) 
ORDER BY LASTDATE DESC;
```

Comment: Please show us your expected result, as tabular text. It is unclear whether you want aggregation, filtering (or both?).

Comment: Please add the expected result. Also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` as shown below:

```
select *
from (
  select
    region,
    sum(case when grade = 'FOOD' then max_capacity else 0 end) as foodgrade,
    sum(case when grade = 'BEV' then max_capacity else 0 end) as bevgrade,
    sum(case when grade = 'IND' then max_capacity else 0 end) as indgrade,
    sum(total_capacity) as totalcapacity,
    sum(total_capacity - max_capacity) as lft,
    max(lastdate) as lastdate
  from txn_viewinfo
  group by region
) x
order by lastdate
```

Comment: works handsomely... thanks alot... but when i add order by lastdate doesnt work.
select
  region_id,
  sum(case when content_typeid = 'CO2-FG' then max_tank_capacity else 0 end) as foodgrade,
  sum(case when content_typeid = 'CO2-BG' then max_tank_capacity else 0 end) as bevgrade,
  sum(case when content_typeid = 'CO2-IG' then max_tank_capacity else 0 end) as indgrade,
  sum(tank_capacity) as totalcapacity,
  sum(tank_capacity - max_tank_capacity) as lft,
  max(LATEST_READTIME) as lastdate
from txn_viewcontainerinfo
group by region_id order by LATEST_READTIME DESC

Comment: and the grade values shows in decimal values like 63.760000000000005

Comment: @uday Fixed. In order to sort by the "computed lastdate" you need to enclose the query as a table expression. This table expression produce the computed lastdate column that you can use to sort.

Comment: works superb.... thanks. pls can i add one more thing... actually i want to display for current Dates only... but the date format is in Timestamp... exp: 2019-12-18 09:49:09.0198.... need to list todays date only...

Comment: @uday Use the `date()` function to retrieve the date part of a timestamp.

Comment: select *
from (
SELECT region_id, 
sum(case when content_typeid = 'CO2-FG' then max_tank_capacity else 0 end) as foodgrade,
sum(case when content_typeid = 'CO2-BG' then max_tank_capacity else 0 end) as bevgrade,
sum(case when content_typeid = 'CO2-IG' then max_tank_capacity else 0 end) as indgrade,
sum(tank_capacity) as totalcapacity,
sum(tank_capacity - max_tank_capacity) as lft, 
from txn_viewcontainerinfo WHERE DATE(LATEST_READTIME) = CURDATE() group by region_id
) x 
order by lastdate; error near 'from txn_viewcontainerinfo WHERE DATE(LATEST_READTIME) = CURDATE() group by regi'

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can gather you are searching for

```
SELECT
  tv.`REGION`
  , SUM(IF(`GRADE` = 'FOOD', 1,0)) Food
  , SUM(IF(`GRADE` = 'BEV', 1,0)) bev
  , SUM(IF(`GRADE` = 'IND', 1,0)) ind
  , MAX(`MAX-CAPACITY`)
  , MAX(`TOTAL-CAPACITY`)
  ,LASTDATE
FROM txn_viewinfo tv INNER JOIN (SELECT `REGION`,MAX(LASTDATE) maxldate 
                                 FROM txn_viewinfo 
                                 GROUP BY `REGION`)  ld
                     ON tv.`LASTDATE` = ld.maxldate AND tv.`REGION` = ld.`REGION`
GROUP BY LASTDATE,`REGION`
ORDER BY LASTDATE DESC;
```

This gives you a count of Grade  at the last day of entry

> ```
> CREATE TABLE txn_viewinfo (
>   `CNT_ID` INTEGER,
>   `REGION` VARCHAR(2),
>   `GRADE` VARCHAR(4),
>   `MAX-CAPACITY` INTEGER,
>   `TOTAL-CAPACITY` INTEGER,
>   `LASTDATE` date
> );
>
> INSERT INTO txn_viewinfo
>   (`CNT_ID`, `REGION`, `GRADE`, `MAX-CAPACITY`, `TOTAL-CAPACITY`, `LASTDATE`)
> VALUES
>   ('1001', 'TN', 'FOOD', '97', '100', '2020-02-17'),
>   ('1001', 'BG', 'BEV', '76', '90', '2020-02-17'),
>   ('1001', 'KA', 'IND', '88', '90', '2020-02-17'),
>   ('1001', 'BG', 'FOOD', '91', '100', '2020-02-17'),
>   ('1001', 'ER', 'IND', '90', '100', '2020-02-15'),
>   ('1001', 'TN', 'FOOD', '78', '80', '2020-02-17'),
>   ('1001', 'TN', 'BEV', '95', '100', '2020-02-17'),
>   ('1001', 'TN', 'FOOD', '92', '100', '2020-02-16'),
>   ('1001', 'TN', 'FOOD', '92', '100', '2020-02-16');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   tv.`REGION`
>   , SUM(IF(`GRADE` = 'FOOD', 1,0)) Food
>   , SUM(IF(`GRADE` = 'BEV', 1,0)) bev
>   , SUM(IF(`GRADE` = 'IND', 1,0)) ind
>   , MAX(`MAX-CAPACITY`)
>   , MAX(`TOTAL-CAPACITY`)
>   ,LASTDATE
> FROM txn_viewinfo tv INNER JOIN (SELECT `REGION`,MAX(LASTDATE) maxldate 
>                                  FROM txn_viewinfo 
>                                  GROUP BY `REGION`)  ld
>                      ON tv.`LASTDATE` = ld.maxldate AND tv.`REGION` = ld.`REGION`
>
> GROUP BY LASTDATE,`REGION`
> ORDER BY LASTDATE DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> REGION | Food | bev | ind | MAX(`MAX-CAPACITY`) | MAX(`TOTAL-CAPACITY`) | LASTDATE  
> :----- | ---: | --: | --: | ------------------: | --------------------: | :---------
> BG     |    1 |   1 |   0 |                  91 |                   100 | 2020-02-17
> KA     |    0 |   0 |   1 |                  88 |                    90 | 2020-02-17
> TN     |    2 |   1 |   0 |                  97 |                   100 | 2020-02-17
> ER     |    0 |   0 |   1 |                  90 |                   100 | 2020-02-15
> ```

> ```
> SELECt tv.*,ld.*
> FROM txn_viewinfo tv INNER JOIN (SELECT `REGION`,MAX(LASTDATE) maxldate 
>                                  FROM txn_viewinfo 
>                                  GROUP BY `REGION`)  ld
>                      ON tv.`LASTDATE` = ld.maxldate AND tv.`REGION` = ld.`REGION`
> #WHERE tv.`LASTDATE` = ld.maxldate
> ```
>
> ```
> CNT_ID | REGION | GRADE | MAX-CAPACITY | TOTAL-CAPACITY | LASTDATE   | REGION | maxldate  
> -----: | :----- | :---- | -----------: | -------------: | :--------- | :----- | :---------
>   1001 | TN     | FOOD  |           97 |            100 | 2020-02-17 | TN     | 2020-02-17
>   1001 | BG     | BEV   |           76 |             90 | 2020-02-17 | BG     | 2020-02-17
>   1001 | KA     | IND   |           88 |             90 | 2020-02-17 | KA     | 2020-02-17
>   1001 | BG     | FOOD  |           91 |            100 | 2020-02-17 | BG     | 2020-02-17
>   1001 | ER     | IND   |           90 |            100 | 2020-02-15 | ER     | 2020-02-15
>   1001 | TN     | FOOD  |           78 |             80 | 2020-02-17 | TN     | 2020-02-17
>   1001 | TN     | BEV   |           95 |            100 | 2020-02-17 | TN     | 2020-02-17
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(IF(GRADE='FOOD',1,NULL)) 'Food'
> , COUNT(IF(GRADE='BEV',1,NULL)) 'Beve'
> , * 
> FROM txn_viewinfo  
> WHERE LASTDATE = (SELECT MAX(LASTDATE) FROM txn_viewinfo ) ORDER BY LATEST_READTIME DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* 
> FROM txn_viewinfo  
> WHERE LASTDATE = (SELECT MAX(LASTDATE) FROM txn_viewinfo ' at line 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c4a99ef357ec7ac79a9b5c9b32762c41)*